# Consulta do banco não bate

Tags: php, sql

Quero usar a tabela agenda para gerenciar o ranking com php quando exibir assim ficaria mais simples e pratico pois o usuário add o jogo na tabela, quando começa a partida já pego dela mesma e se precisar editar um jogo que já passou fica já atualiza tudo de uma vez, o problema é que travei nessa parte. na tabela as colunas **timea** e **timeb** são chaves estrangeiras que tem a possibilidade de um (time que caiu na coluna **timea**) mais pra frente cair na coluna **timeb** por isso tentei amarrar pelo nome do time que vem da outra tabela .
meu complicado pra explica por isso se tiver uma outra logica pra indicar agradeço como é para estudo não preciso ficar preso em um prospecto, o mais perto que consegui foi isso mas os dados não batem ele acrescenta +1 em alguns campos

```
SELECT R.r_time_id as ID_Equipe, t.nome_time as Nome_Equipe,
       SUM(A.jogoa*3) as Pontos,
       SUM(A.jogoa+ AG.jogob ) as Jogos,
       SUM(A.gola + AG.golb) as Total_Gol,
       COUNT(A.v_a + AG.v_b )AS VIT,COUNT(A.e_a + AG.e_b )AS EMP,
       COUNT(A.d_a + AG.d_b)AS DER
FROM `ranking` R
INNER JOIN agenda A ON A.timea=R.r_time_id
INNER JOIN times t ON R.r_time_id=t.id    
INNER JOIN agenda AG On Ag.timeb=R.r_time_id
WHERE R.r_time_id=1
```

[image: tabela times]
[image: tabela da agenda]

Comment: O que você pretende com `COUNT(A.v_a + AG.v_b )`?

Comment: coloquei o o SQL incompleto e não percebi, mas a ideia é que ele conte a vitória quando o time cair na coluna a ou na coluna b

Comment: Recomendo que você estude como NULL é tratado. Uma expressão que contenha NULL sempre resultará em NULL e COUNT sempre irá ignorar NULL.